# How to create Mavericks OSX ISO from app

Tags: windows-7, osx-mavericks, iso

I have a Windows 7 computer and want to install OSX Mavericks on Windows using VirtualBox, I have the downloaded OSX as a Install OS X Mavericks.app folder.

Is there any way/program under Windows I can use to convert this into a bootable ISO file to install it in VirtualBox

Comment: You should try Superuser for such question

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about Superuser...